# LESS.app running with 100% CPU usage

Tags: css, macos, less, cpu-usage

I running os x 10.6.8 and up until now, I've been compiling with LESS.app perfectly.
Now when the app begins to compile a .less file, a process starts called "node" and its CPU usage rises to 100%.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app, but this has no effect. I'm not sure what I could have done to cause this.

Has anyone else experienced this problem, and if so do you have any solutions?

Comment: Have you deleted everything related to the app? Or did you just remove it from your Applications directory?
I'd try using some kind of tool like "Clean My Mac" to get rid of everything and reinstall...

Comment: I actually did exactly that, I have "Clean My Mac" and I used it remove all related files before I reinstalled. However, it had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to update Codekit.app ?

http://incident57.com/codekit/

> Less.app will be maintained with new versions of Less.js until at least 2015. However, the app itself will not see any new features. I'm focused on making CodeKit insanely awesome. CodeKit is the future, so you should check it out!

from http://incident57.com/less/

Comment: Sorry for this answer. Codekit is required 10.7+.

Comment: It's fine, Codekit looks pretty cool. I'll try it out if I update to 10.7.

Comment: Just thought I'd post a little update here. I read this post back in 2012 when I too was having problems with LESS.app using a LOT of resources. I made the switch to CodeKit. Now I've got exactly the same (if not worse) problem with CodeKit. It regularly locks up and gets to 100% CPU if its got a large number of files to manage. I love the app but from a scalability perspective, its junk. Sadly there seems to be no alternatives out there either!